# How to prevent disclosure button being triggered on a UITableViewCell when swiping left

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This seems like a simple enough problem but I can't seem to find a solution.

I have a table view that has cells with the disclosure button. I'm using accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath to trigger the click on the button so that it takes the user to an info page.

I also have the swipe left to delete action set up on the cell.

The problem is, when the user swipes left, but while doing so touches the disclosure button, both actions occur (meaning accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath gets fired, but also the swipe left happens).

Is there any way to prevent this? I would like that when the swipe happens, only "swipe left to delete" occurs and the info page does not fire (which should only fire upon a click).

Comment: you can move code of `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. So that it will fire when you tap cell not the disclosure button

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing something similar, I made a custom button and put my limited graphics design skills on the line. I would have done it your way but I needed the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for something else =)

Comment: Anyway, there's the workaround, but if there's a better solution i'd still like to hear it.

Comment: you can add another action as `info` or whatever beside `delete` action on swiping cell to left..only if you are ok with it. But in this case user will have to swipe left and then only can find option for `info`

Comment: Yeah, that would certainly work, but in usage terms it wouldn't be immediately obvious to the user. The custom button is doing exactly what I wanted at the moment, so my problem is solved. I just thought there might be a built in solution to it, that's what I meant by "better solution", sorry for bad wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll attempt to explain what I think was going on. The function accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath seems to bind the accessory button to a touch up inside event, which gets fired when you do a drag and lift up your finger after because your finger is still inside the button (which followed the drag).

I worked around this by using a custom button and attaching an UITapGestureRecongnizer to it.